# How can I dissable remember_me on Laravel 5

Tags: laravel

I don't keep `remember_me` in my table but when I logout Laravel try to update `remember_me` column and it cause the error. this is error that happen

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 669:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'remember_token' in
              'field list' (SQL: update `users` set `remember_token` = 
              fwKUGSHY7ozXdYe56TnmFgBYY2FkH1XxT8A6EeFQ5wVHzMC9bq1EsROjn8YF where `id` = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is if you're using Laravel 5.2 default authentication system, you cannot remove `remember_me` manually form the `users` table (which you did I guess).

Easiest way to disable remember me feature is to remove this from `auth/login.blade.php` view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, add `remember_me` back to the database to make Laravel work as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Once check this below url

[Disable remember token](http://laravel.io/forum/05-21-2014-how-to-disable-remember-token)